# In firebase storage i need to send a photo twice before it gets saved

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

(sorry for my english)(sorry if this question is irrelevant i am new to programing)So i am making a chat app but when i try to send a photo it doesn't send, only if i send it twice it saves in the db.

Here is the warning i get in logcat:

```
06-17 17:12:27.685 927-1000/? E/WifiConfigStore: updateConfiguration freq=2442 BSSID=f4:f2:6d:67:54:e8 RSSI=-59 "TP-LINK_54E8"WPA_PSK06-17 17:12:27.831 10830-11008/com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
Object does not exist at location.
 Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
{  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"  }}
java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"  }}
    at bha.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12685024@12.6.85 (040406-197041431):147)
    at bha.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12685024@12.6.85 (040406-197041431):119)
    at bgu.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12685024@12.6.85 (040406-197041431):7)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:392)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zza.transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzm.zze(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzq.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_storage.zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.zzc.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)06-17 17:12:28.091 927-927/? E/WifiTrafficPoller: TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 1236 num clients 10
 packet count Tx=1047457 Rx=3285705 06-17 17:12:29.092 927-927/? E/WifiTrafficPoller: TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 1236 num clients 10
 packet count Tx=1047458 Rx=3285706
```

and here is the code :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        StorageReference photoRef = mSRreference.child(selectedImageUri.toString());
        photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri);
        photoRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(
            new OnSuccessListener<Uri>()

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri)
            {
                Message m = new Message(null, mUsername, uri.toString());
                mDbReference.push().setValue(m);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

here

Comment: I think you have to wait for the `putFile` to complete before attempting to get the download url. [Here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/storage/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/firebasestorage/MyUploadService.java#L113) is an example

Comment: I just fixed it by adding the .continueWithTask method, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

[putFile()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#putFile(android.net.Uri)) returns a [UploadTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask) that eventually indicates that the file was successfully uploaded.  You need to use that task.  It looks like you're already familiar with tasks, because you're already using the one returned by getDownloadUrl() to determine when that data is available.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
StorageReference photoRef = mSRreference.child(selectedImageUri.toString());
photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new 
OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot){
        //taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()
        Message m = new Message(null, mUsername, taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
        mDbReference.push().setValue(m);
    }

    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        }
});
```

This will do your job.